# what's the best way to execute fast aggregation queries based on YEAR and MONTH filters in addition to dynamic filters

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, partitioning, amazon-rds

My SQL table is going to have millions of rows. Currently, with only 2M rows, my aggregation queries take anywhere between 20 seconds to a minute.

The filters in WHERE clause for aggregation queries are going to be based on user-selected values of filters from different combinations of those filters.

I intend to make a selection of "YEAR" and "MONTH" filter mandatory which should narrow down the number of rows to get the aggregates on. However, it does not seem to be making much of a difference with YEAR and Month filter .

For ex:

```
select `importer_name`, ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) AS top15_usd
from   `importer_bills`
WHERE  
bill_of_entry_year=2020
AND
bill_of_entry_month = 3
AND 
...ANY COMBINATION OF USER SELECTED FILTERS
group  by `importer_name`
order  by ROUND(SUM(total_value_usd_exchange), 2) desc limit 15 offset 0;
```

Output of explain for this query:

```
1   SIMPLE  importer_bills  p0  ref idx_importer_bills_upwork_09,idx_importer_bills_year_month  idx_importer_bills_year_month   5   const,const 1106762 100.00  Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

However, irrespective of this example query,  I am looking for a way to add some level of optimization based on the fact that the queries will always have YEAR AND MONTH filter which considerably reduces the size of data to aggregate on. I had hoped partitioning was the way to go.

I tried to partition data by YEAR as well but that did not help either. Since users may or may not select filters from the other 7 filterable columns, It's unnecessary to create complex indexes. I have already created simple indexes on those columns that data can be filtered on. What can be done to have a reasonable speed of aggregation queries here?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE importer_bills\G` please?

Comment: Also, your version of MySQL - this is **always** a good idea and **more** critical for MySQL than for the other major servers, given the way it has been piling in the features recently!

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain one (or maybe a small number) Summary table.  Then run queries against it.  The 20 seconds is likely to drop to under 3.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

In general, it is much better to use a single `DATE` column instead of separate column for year and month.  Explain further what is going on; I can't tell whether it is practical here.